# Perl regex inserting multiple spaces in string

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace, substitution

To load my file, I need a string to be delimited by multiple spaces. I do not want to do a global replace since there are several lines of data in my file that should not be altered.  Instead, I would like only alter the space between my headers "number" and "numbers". Currently my output looks like:

```
count          number numbers
```

I would like each of my words to be separated by multiple spaces and look more like this:

```
count          number          numbers
```

I am coding in Perl have tried using regular expressions similar to:

```
s/number" "numbers/number" "{4}numbers/;
```

Should I try a different approach from the substitution command?

Comment: `" "{4}` doesn't work like this on the replacement side. Try something like `s/number\s+numbers/number    numbers/g` where put 4 spaces in the replacement.

Comment: So are you saying that you want four spaces between the values in the second and third columns? Or are `number` and `numbers` not always the second and third columns? A proper example of your data would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=number)\s(?=numbers)
```

You can use `lookahead` for this.Replace by .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/18